# urllib и русский текст

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь спарсить текст с русского сайта

```
import urllib.request
import re
url = 'https://ru.wordpress.org/'
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()
paragraphs = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>', str(respData))    #ищем все что между этими тэгами     
for eachP in paragraphs:
    print(eachP)
```

В ответ получаю каракули вида

> \xe2\x80\x94
>   \xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f
>   \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1

Если подставить любой англоязычный ресурс, то отрабатывает без проблем

```
url = 'https://wordpress.org/news/'
```

> The release also includes hardening for a potential cross-site
>   scripting vulnerability when using the visual editor. This issue was
>   reported by Mahadev Subedi.

Подскажите как получить русский текст?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону requests - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ или aiohttp - https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp

Comment: в тему: [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы загрузили с сервера последовательность байт (bytes). Надо раскодировать ее, преобразовав в строку (string), прежде чем разбирать регулярками.

Как-то так:

```
respData = resp.read().decode(resp.headers.get_content_charset())
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь буду знать про decode :)

Comment: Так это исправление у вас заработало или нет? Если нет, напишите почему. Если да, отметьте ответ зеленой галочкой :)

Comment: Да это исправление мне помогло получить русский текст)

Comment: В случае, если http-ответ не содержит Content-Type заголовок с charset параметром, то необходимо содержимое смотреть, чтобы кодировку узнать, например `<meta charset="utf-8">`. [`text = bs4.UnicodeDammit(content, is_html=True).unicode_markup`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14592894/4279)